# Has any civilian ship been trapped in the mirror universe?

Tags: star-trek, mirror-universe

I'm talking about ordinary non-Starfleet or Federation vessels: for example, you built your own vessel and some how manage to end up in the mirror universe with minimal to no weapons, no logs of any kind from other ships, and no additional data to help you.

We've seen ships like this before in canon, [ENT: Horizon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Horizon_(episode)), so imagine a ship like that being pulled into and trapped in the mirror universe.